# Can Apache Drill read Apache ORC file format?

Tags: apache-drill, orc

Can Apache Drill read ORC files?

Comment: Apache drill cannot read ORC. But Apache Spark has been optimized for ORC support. Check [this](https://hortonworks.com/blog/bringing-orc-support-into-apache-spark/) out for further info

Answer (score 5):

This answer was posted by user agirish in Apache Drill mailing lists. Copying here for it to be useful for this community.

> Drill can read ORC format files via the Hive plugin. If you have a
>   Hive table with underlying data stored as ORC, try and configure the
>   Hive storage plugin in Drill [[1]](http://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/). And then
>   you can attempt to query the table in Hive from Drill [[2]](http://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-hive/).